# Angular9 - cannot access other module after using shared service

Tags: angular, angular9

I'm working on Angular 9 using lazy loading concept. There's something wrong while I'm working.

For example,

I have **User** and **Role** modules. I implement SharedService on User module. But when I click on menu for Role module, It will show error

> Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError:
>   R3InjectorError(RoleModule)[SharedService -> SharedService ->
>   SharedService -> SharedService]:    NullInjectorError: No provider for
>   SharedService!

Here is my shared service code for **User Module**,

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    sendMessage(message: any) {
        this.subject.next(message);
    }

    clearMessages() {
        this.subject.next();
    }

    getMessage(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }

}
```

In the **user.module.ts** I add

```
providers:[
  SharedService
]
```

already.

Even I copy a shared service file to Role module and add provider to the role.module.ts, It still show the same error. It seems like I cannot use shared service for my project.

Comment: Does RoleModule use shared service?

Answer (score 0):

Use provideIn: root in injectable decorator :-

```
@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})
```

and remove this service from provider array of any module.